# Add Textbox into DataTable

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have DataGridView that i am adding items via DataTable before adding into my `DataGridview`:

```
private void UpdateDataGdirView(List<Vendor> list)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Column1", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
    dt.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Column3", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
    dt.Columns.Add("Column4", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
    dt.Columns.Add("Column5", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
    dt.Columns.Add("Column6", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
    DataRow dr;

    foreach (Vendor vendor in list)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Column1"] = vendor.IsVendorChecked;
        dr["Column2"] = vendor.Number;
        dr["Column3"] = vendor.Name;
        dr["Column4"] = vendor.Size;
        dr["Column5"] = vendor.Path;
        dr["Column6"] = vendor.Path2;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
    dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; });
}
```

I have try:
`dataTable.Columns.Add("test", System.Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.TextBox"));`

and got error:  'dataType' argument cannot be null.

Now i want to add in  the last column `TextBox`
how can i do that ?

Comment: In which control you see `Vendor.Number`? Isn't it `TextBox`?

Comment: My DataGridView, i am binding DataTable into my DataGridview: dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

Answer (score 0):

Your `Vendor.Number` shown in the [DataGridViewTextBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewtextboxcolumn.aspx), so if your data bound to the column is of type `string` it will automatically shown in [DataGridViewTextBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewtextboxcolumn.aspx) i.e. in `TextBox`.